# Can't add item to iesi.collections.generic.iset

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many, iesi-collections

Trying to add item to iset, but it doesn't happens.

```
var controlPoint = new ControlPoint {Lon = 53.25253, Lat = 56.23422, Radius = 16};
//controlPoint.ApprovedRoutes = new HashedSet<ApprovedRoute>();
controlPoint.Save();

var route = new ApprovedRoute();
route.ControlPoints = new HashedSet<ControlPoint>();
route.ControlPoints.Add(controlPoint);
route.Name = "sometext";
route.Save();

//controlPoint.ApprovedRoutes.Add(route);
//controlPoint.Save();
```

classes:

```
public class GeoPoint: Entity<long>
{
    public virtual double Lon { get; set; }
    public virtual double Lat { get; set; }
}

public class ControlPoint: GeoPoint
{
    public virtual double Radius { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<ApprovedRoute> ApprovedRoutes { get; set; }
}

public class ApprovedRoute : Entity<long>
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<ControlPoint> ControlPoints { get; set; }
}
```

here's mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Transport" namespace="Transport.Models">
  <class name="GeoPoint" table="GeoPoint">
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="id" not-null="true" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Lon" />
    <property name="Lat" />

    <joined-subclass name="ControlPoint" table="ControlPoint">
      <key column="Id"/>
      <property name="Radius"/>

      <set name="ApprovedRoutes" table="M_ApprovedRoute_ControlPoint" inverse="true">
        <key column="PointId"></key>
        <many-to-many column="RouteId" class="ApprovedRoute" />
      </set>

    </joined-subclass>  
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

one more:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Transport" namespace="Transport.Models">
  <class name="ApprovedRoute" table="ApprovedRoute">
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="id" not-null="true" />
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />   
    <set name="ControlPoints" table="M_ApprovedRoute_ControlPoint">
      <key column="RouteId"></key>
      <many-to-many column="PointId" class="ControlPoint" />
    </set>    
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

what I'm doing wrong? ControlPoint and ApprovedRoute records appears in tables, but M_ApprovedRoute_ControlPoint is still empty.

p.s. .Save() calls Session.SaveOrUpdate(obj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so easy. I just wrap SaveOrUpdate in a transaction and now it's work!

```
using (ITransaction tx = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                Session.SaveOrUpdate(obj);
                Session.Flush();
                tx.Commit();
            }
            catch (HibernateException)
            {
                tx.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
```